# React how to add defaultChecked in ToggleButtonGroup

Tags: javascript, reactjs

These is my code

```
<ToggleButtonGroup name='plotType' value={plotType} type="radio" onSelect={handlePlot} vertical={false} >
                        METROLOGY_TYPE_SHOW_PLOT[metrologyType].map((key, index) => (
        <OverlayTrigger
            key={index}
            placement="right"
            overlay={<Tooltip id="button-tooltip-2">{key}</Tooltip>}>
            <ToggleButton id={key} value={key}
                          variant="link"
                          size='sm'> 
                  <img alt={key} src={getIconUrl(key)}/>
            </ToggleButton>
        </OverlayTrigger>
</ToggleButtonGroup>
```

I try to add defaultChecked and defaulValue in ToggleButtonGroup ,but it didn't worked

I want to set the defaultValue and the button have default border.

Comment: Please put your all code

Comment: Where does `ToggleButtonGroup` component come from? A third-party package?